# Hora em Java que conta os segundos em tempo real

Tags: java, datetime

Quero mostrar a hora do sistema e com os segundos a contar em tempo real em Java.

Comment: Não entendi, o que é "a contar em tempo real em Java"?

Comment: @bigown, observa, se mostrares a hora, os minutos e segundos em java, irá apresentar de forma estática, ou seja, os segundos ficarão apenas aqueles que a última vez foi pego ... eu quero poder apresenta-lo dinâmico a contar desde 01 ... 59 ... percebes?

Comment: E você quer fazer isto como? Quer mostrar onde?

Comment: @bigown, quero mostrar no ecrã ... fazendo um System.out.println ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode usar o agendador de serviços do Java para exibir as horas a cada um segundo.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Relogio {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
          new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
              }
        }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Não há necessidade de usar a classe `Thread`, nem usar o método `sleep` e nem fazer tratamento incorreto de exceção.

Comment: Obrigado mano, você é o cara ;)

Comment: Muito bom o código,bem mais limpo e legível do que aprendi fazer. Não conhecia esse `ScheduledExecutorService` dar uma olhada nele. Creio que posso otimizar alguns de meus códigos. Valeu!

Answer (score 4):

Segundo [essa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15579938/221800) dá para fazer assim:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() { //cria uma thread
            public void run() {
                while(true) { //roda indefinidamente
                    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); //pega a hora do sistema
                    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    String today = formatter.format(date);      
                    System.out.println(today);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000); //espera 1 segundo para fazer a nova evolução
                    } catch(InterruptedException ex){
                        //é algo terrível a se fazer mas pelo jeito a API medonha do Java exige
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        th.start();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iWv4Um). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kergrtqc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/DateFormat.java).

Pode não dar o melhor resultado mas é isto. Não há garantias que todas as atualizações de tela ocorrerão a cada 1 segundo exato.

Tem como posicionar o cursor sempre na mesma posição mas como não tenho como testar vou só deixar o código para você tentar:

```
System.out.print(String.format("%c[%d;%df", 0x1B, 0, 0));
```

Comment: obrigado. Funcionou! Valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Penso que é isto que pretende

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class relogio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {  
            while (true) {  
                Date d = new Date();  
                StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();  

                    SimpleDateFormat sdfData = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");  
                    data.append(sdfData.format(d));  
                    data.append(" - ");  

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");  
                System.out.println(""+data.toString() + sdf.format(d));

                Thread.sleep(1000);  
            }  
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {  
            System.out.println("Problema na atualização da data/hora");  
            ex.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela disposição, @jsantos1991 ... funcionou ;)